# How can I setup flow to check ALL files in create react app without checking node_modules?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, create-react-app

I recently started a new React project using `create-react-app`. From the beginning I have been integrating flow into all of the files, and it has  been working wonderfully!

After adding `// @flow` to the beginning of every new file created in the project, I wanted to bypass this and have flow automatically check all files without needing the comment at the top. As the documentation suggests, I changed my `.flowconfig` file to be

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*

[include]

[libs]

[lints]

[options]
all=true

[strict]
```

After adding these two lines, any time I try to run `flow` from the terminal the process ultimately waits on the message `flow is still initializing; this can take some time. [merging inference]` (I waited for about 5 minutes and the message never went away). After removing the `all` option, it began working quickly as expected.

My question then is **how can I use the `all` option in this situation and still have flow work in an ordinary amount of time?** I'm assuming it's because flow is still looking in node_modules and is taking a long time to figure out that folder, but I can't seem to make flow ignore it like I want. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Immediately after posting this question, I realized maybe I wasn't ignoring enough. After ignoring the build folder as well I was able to get flow to work as I was expecting.  This is how my `.flowconfig` file ended up

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*
.*/build/.*

[include]

[libs]

[lints]

[options]
all=true

[strict]
```

Hopefully this helps someone else in the same situation!